# AngularJS expression converts number into string after change

Tags: angularjs

I have a couple of inputs like this:

```
<input type='range' min='15' max='{{plan.retirementAge - 1}}' name='age' ng-model='plan.age' />
<input type='range' min='{{plan.age + 1}}' max='90' name='retirementAge' ng model='plan.retirementAge' />
```

This works correctly when the page first loads, but if I change either value the other one will treat the binding as a string and change it to "37" + 1 = "371" instead of 38. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because Angular doesn't yet implement a handler for `type="range"` like it does with `type="number"`, etc. You should probably report this on their Github site (under Issues).

In the mean time, you can get around it like this. That is, create your own `range-model` and add a parser to `ngModelController` that converts the value to a number.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.age = 10;
        $scope.retirementAge = 65;
    })
    .directive('rangeModel', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
                    return parseInt(val, 10);
                });
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type='range' min='15' max='{{retirementAge - 1}}' range-model name='age' ng-model='age' />
    {{age}}
    <input type='range' min='{{age + 1}}' max='90' name='retirementAge' range-model ng-model='retirementAge' />
    {{retirementAge}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah as a shortcut for now I just added an `add(first,second)` method to my scope. Not ideal but it will do for now and it's obvious it should be removed at some point.

Comment: Using `min='{{add(plan.age, 1)}}'` works, but then you have to convert plan.age everytime you use it. By adding a $parser, you're making sure that the model will always be a number.

Comment: It's ok it isn't permanent. I've already submitted a pull request for this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1189